# KL Divergence estimation

Tags: analysis, information-theory, information-geometry, robust-statistics

I am trying to construct a certain bound for the KL divergence between two two numbers. I want to show that $-n D((a+s/\sqrt{n}|| a)\le -\frac{s}{2a(1-a)}+Error(1/\sqrt{n})$ $(a\in(0,1))$

\begin{align*}
     e^{-nD(a+\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}||a)}&=\exp\Big(-n\Big(\big(a+\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}\big)\log\frac{a+\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}{a}+\big(1-a-\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}\big)\log\frac{1-a-\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}{1-a}\Big)\Big)\\
     &=\exp\Big(\big(-na-{s\sqrt{n}}\log\frac{a+\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}{a}+\big(n-a n-{s\sqrt{n}}\big)\log\frac{1-a-\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}{1-a}\Big)\Big)\\
 \end{align*}
I want to use $\log(x)\le x-1$ but I dont see where this is possible.

Comment: The expression you want to show is weird. $D \ge 0,$ so $-nD$ is already smaller than anything positive. I assume that you want to show that $nD$ is small. Also, the scaling of $nD$ with $s$ as $n \to \infty$ is as $s^2$, not as $s$. Anyway, since you only want big-O control on the error, why not just run a Taylor expansion on $D(a + \varepsilon\|a)$ (as a function of $\varepsilon$)? You can also invoke the Peano form of the remainder if you like and derive explicit bounds on the error term as well.

Comment: sorry, there was a minor typo, I fixed it